# Quarkus - How to create mock with a specific behavior for my test method

Tags: unit-testing, mockito, quarkus

By following the Quarkus's guide, about the mock support for testing (https://quarkus.io/guides/getting-started-testing#mock-support). I dont see a clear and good way to build specific scenarios of testing for my services, like different scenarios for each method.

I find it pretty easy to do with mockito but i havent found nothing about integration of Quarkus and Mockito (Actually that would be amazing).

Is there a way to achieve that in Quarkus, the lack of that is a big problem for me!!

EDIT

By the way even by following the example i cant mock the emitter of my Resource, it is not getting replaced

```
@Mock
@ApplicationScoped
public class EmitterMock implements Emitter<KafkaMessage<String, String>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently @Mock is very limited, unfortunately. You can use mockito, just add mockito-core as a dependency the normal way and use it in your unit tests (without @QuarkusTest annotation)